# Pillow: splitting a spritesheet into seprate images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a [spritesheet](https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/smicons-sheet.png) with sprites of 40x30 each, and I'm trying to split it up into indivdual sprites named from `0-number_of_sprites`

```
from PIL import Image
from os import mkdir

mkdir("assets/icons")
sheet = Image.open("assets/icons.png")
count = 0

for x in range(12):
    for y in range(97):
        a = (x + 1) * 40
        b = (y + 1) * 30
        icon = sheet.crop((a - 40, b - 30, a, b))  # Problem here
        icon.save("assets/icons/{}.png".format(count))
        count += 1
```

And the problem is where I marked as such. The coordinates of `a, b` are the top left and top right of each sprite, going from `40, 30` to `480, 2910`

EDIT: Put in where the problem was, accidently deleted it before. My problem is this code gets each indivdual sprite, but seems to do it in a completly random order, for instance #384 on the list, was saved as #32 for some reason, and #10 as #1

Comment: Where did you mark the problem. Please [edit] your question and do this (and adding an explanation of the issue would be even better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you crop your spritesheet column by column instead of row by row. This means that the first sprite on the second row is cropped second instead of thirteenth. Bulbasaur is actually the 98th sprite you crop. You need to switch the order of your `for` loops:

```py
for y in range(97):
    for x in range(12):
        ...
```

I suggest you set `count` to 1, this way your first icon will be numbered 1 instead of 0. You might also want to use something like `str(count).zfill(4)` so that your icons are sorted properly in your file manager. Just two little nitpicks.

Comment: Thanks alot! that was indeed the problem, as a sidenote, Im using the ? icon, and I want pokemon (for the most part, forms wont work) to be labeld by national dex #, so I dont start at 1. Also for me (thunar on linux) sorting by # works is the default

Comment: Fair enough. Might still be a good idea to pad the number if you need to list the contents of your folder with Python and get the icons in order, for example, but it depends on your needs.